# Create azure virtual machine with image Flexify.io with command

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I can create a virtual machine with the UI :

[image]

via Azure marketplace with [Flexify.io](http://flexify.io/), however, I want to use the command since I want the VM to be created when it's secured (SSL).

These are the image for `Flexify.io` :

https://hub.docker.com/r/flexifyio/ce/tags

So I tried to use the command below :

```
az vm create     --resource-group myresourcegroups     --name staging-images     --image flexifyio/ce:latest    --admin-username azureuser     --generate-ssh-keys     --custom-data ~/Documents/cloud-init-web-server.txt     --secrets "$vm_secret"
```

This is the flexify.io image `flexifyio/ce:latest`, but am getting this error :

```
Invalid image "flexifyio/ce:latest". Use a valid image URN, custom image name, custom image id, VHD blob URI, or pick an image from ['CentOS', 'Debian', 'Flatcar', 'openSUSE-Leap', 'RHEL', 'SLES', 'UbuntuLTS', 'Win2022Datacenter', 'Win2022AzureEditionCore', 'Win2019Datacenter', 'Win2016Datacenter', 'Win2012R2Datacenter', 'Win2012Datacenter', 'Win2008R2SP1'].
See VM create -h for more information on specifying an image.
```

How best can I do this?

Comment: The `--image` argument accepts references to images available in the Azure marketplace. Have you verified that the image in question is available there by running `az vm image show`? How exactly did you reach the conclusion that a VM could be built from a Docker Hub image as you seem to be trying to do here?

Comment: Well, I was following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-secure-web-server

Comment: I also added a screenshot to show you that =, I could select the image for Flexify.io, so I though I could do the same with the command by getting the image name from dockerhub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--image` argument for `az vm` commands can be used to reference an image available on the Azure Marketplace, not Docker Hub (or any other repository, for that matter). Azure Marketplace is also the source of the images you see in the VM creation flow in the Azure Portal.

To find the identifier for the image you want to create your VM with, use `az vm image list --all --publisher Flexify`, which yields some results:

```
[
  {
    "architecture": "x64",
    "offer": "migration-vm",
    "publisher": "flexify-io",
    "sku": "migration-vm-ce",
    "urn": "flexify-io:migration-vm:migration-vm-ce:2.12.10",
    "version": "2.12.10"
  },
  {
    "architecture": "x64",
    "offer": "multi-cloud",
    "publisher": "flexify-io",
    "sku": "multi-cloud-vm-ce",
    "urn": "flexify-io:multi-cloud:multi-cloud-vm-ce:2.12.0",
    "version": "2.12.0"
  },
  {
    "architecture": "x64",
    "offer": "multi-cloud",
    "publisher": "flexify-io",
    "sku": "multi-cloud-vm-ce",
    "urn": "flexify-io:multi-cloud:multi-cloud-vm-ce:2.12.2",
    "version": "2.12.2"
  },
  {
    "architecture": "x64",
    "offer": "single-vm",
    "publisher": "flexify-io",
    "sku": "single-vm-ce",
    "urn": "flexify-io:single-vm:single-vm-ce:2.12.10",
    "version": "2.12.10"
  }
]
```

Then pass the `urn` value of the image you *want* to deploy to your VM like so:

```
az vm create --resource-group myresourcegroups --name staging-images --image flexify-io:single-vm:single-vm-ce:2.12.10 --admin-username azureuser --generate-ssh-keys     --custom-data ~/Documents/cloud-init-web-server.txt --secrets "$vm_secret"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, actually had just got the answer :)